# How to connect the UITabBarController to 3 different screens?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I just created the UITabBarController and then I embedded the NavigationController into it.

The issue I am having now is that I am not sure how to add tab bar items. Right now I just have one item that goes to the home screen. But what do I do to add tabs to that tabbarcontroller?

I tried control-dragging it to other controllers, but I think that is not the way to go here.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using Storyboards.

If you right click on the Tab Bar view controller connections icon (the round golden icon on the left) or select the connections inspector (on the right) while you've got your navigation controller selected in the storyboard you'll see a "View Controllers" option under "Triggered Segues". Simply drag from that circle to the new view controller you want to be linked in your tab bar controller and voila, new tab bar item.

Answer (score 2):

Tab bar items are automatically added based on how many view controllers the UITabBarController has.

For example when you call:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
```

2 tab bar items will be created automatically for you.

Comment: thanks - so does that mean that the tab bar items can only be added programmatically? And also, where do I place that code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do all of that from the beginning.  If you start a project that is a tabbar project you will automatically get two tabs.  If you want more, drag a view controller over from the right pane under objects.  Then control click and drag from the root view to the new view controller and select relationship tabbar.  You can hook up as many as you want without the code.  Hope this helps you out.